# Not able to remove the Custom Cell from UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I am using Custom Cell for `UITableView` and there is a `UIButton` on it which should remove the current cell from the table view. 
In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I am doing

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    NSLog(@"Creating Cell");

    FADynamicCell *cell= (FADynamicCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([FADynamicCell class])
                                             owner:nil
                                           options:nil] lastObject];
    }

    currentIndexPath = indexPath;

    UIButton *removeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    removeButton.tag = indexPath.row +100;
    removeButton.frame =  cell.removeButton.frame;
    removeButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255./255 green:65./255 blue: 21./255 alpha:1];
    removeButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    removeButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [removeButton setTitle:@"Remove" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [removeButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [removeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(removing) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell addSubview:removeButton];

    return cell;
}
```

And in Function for removing

```
-(void) removing
{
    [TOperations deleteTickerFromGroup:tickerGroupID andTickerSymbol:selectedSymbol];

    NSNumber *selectedRowIndex1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:currentIndexPath.row];
    [tableView1 beginUpdates];
    NSIndexPath *previousPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedRowIndex1.integerValue-1 inSection:0];
    [tableView1 endUpdates];
    [tableView1 reloadData];

}
```

Now problem is that it is showing animation on the correct cell but I am not able to remove the custom cell from the table view. And whenever I load the view again i.e. comes from other screen it does not shows the cell on which I have clicked for removing.

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: The problem may be in your data source. Check if the item still exists when you comes from other screen.

Comment: @Sviatoslav Yakymiv: When I coming from other screen then it does not exists if I have pressed remove button previously

Comment: @Atul from your above code, it seems data source of your tableview is missing. You should use some array/dictionary to keep track of cells to create and which is removed etc..

Comment: @Janak Nirmal: I am using sqlite to store the data. It does not reduce the count at current click but it reduces the count when viewDidLoad is executed

Comment: You must set the removeButton.tag in the willDisplayCellForRowAtIndexPath method or you may end with button with wrong indexPath whenever you delete a cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete a row/cell from table view, you need to call the `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` method on your `UITableView` instance.

```
NSIndexPath *previousPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedRowIndex1.integerValue-1 inSection:0];
[self.yourTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:previousPath]  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

This will update the UI, but remember to remove that row from your data source as well. This will ensure it is deleted completely.

Hope that helps!

Comment: :When I am using your code code it crashes and shows: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: This happens because you're not updating your data source, which is still returning the same number of rows in the method `numberOfRowsForSection:`

Comment: @Atul Are you sure the indexPath is being calculated correctly? Also ensure to delete the particular row from data source.

Comment: @micantox: I was doing the wrong in numberOfRowsForSection thanks for your answer